# How to get my app stats on itunes?

Tags: itunes

I have recently published one iPhone app but I don't see any way to check the app stats just like in Google Play.

Would you please tell me how to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by App Status? 
If you want to know your sales, the reviews to your app etc you have to log into iTunes Connect!

Comment: @Pheel: in Google Play I can see how many downloads, how many active users, from which country, what android version are users using, etc. but I don't see anything like that in itunes. Note: my app is for free

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it from [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/).

Log into your account, then, to check the amount of downloads, go to **Sales and Trends**.

The downloads stats are updated once a day.

To check the user reviews, pricing etc, go to **Manage your Applications**, select the app you want and from there you can see:

- **Customer reviews**
- **Set a price for your app**
- **Manage Game Center or Set up iAD network** (if your apps use iAd).
- **Set inApp Purchases** *(if your app uses iAP)*

By clicking again to your app's icon, you'll be able to check details about your app, such as

- **Version Summary** *a little summary that lets you check how your app appears in stores*
- **Crash Reports** *lets you check for crash reports*
- **Binary Details** *a little summary about the binary*
- **Status History** *a little history about the app's status*
- **Customer Reviews** *(again)*

and to edit the app's metadata, such as description, screenshots, localizations etc.

Then you can also check your payments (if you'll publish a paid app) and much more.

What you can't check is the iOS version users are using, though.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. However, can you also tell me what do they mean with Units in Sales & Trends? is it number of downloads

Comment: Yes it is. They are basically the number of downloads for state.

Comment: thanks again. Just to clear one thing, what do you mean with "Downloads for state"? is that number of downloads in the United States only? if yes, iTunes doesn't give number of downloads from other countries?

Comment: E.G: United States - Units: 100. That means that in the USA you sold (or people downloaded) 100 units FOR TODAY. Yes then, iTunes gives the number of units for every country

Answer (score 1):

I think all the information Pheel has provided was correct is still correct to extend but Apple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had.
I personally like this stat screen better than the previous stat screen which apple used to provide because you can adjust the dates on one screen and see how many downloads you have had.[image]