# How to count newUsers per device ? Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I am using google analytics in my ios/android apps.

I need to count the following:

1. new downloads : when user download the application from the store for the first time.
2. reDownload : when user download the application from the store after uninstalling it.

---

*here is an example:*

when **"user A"** download the application from the store for the **first time** then it count as **new download**.

when **"user A"** **delete** the application then after some time **"user A" download** the application **again** from the store , this count as **reDownload**.

---

*please note*:

**newUsers metric** count **new downloads** + **reDownload** together. because every time the user install the application google sdk create new user.

---

*my solution:*

ios / android has a unique **advertisinId** which is constant and doesn't change regularly .

so i would create a **custom dimension** called **advertisinId** with **user level scope .**

and then i need to create two custom metric:

1. first one which is count unique advertisinId
2. second one which is count advertisinId who has more than one user.

How to do build those metrics ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need Google Analytics for this, when you upload your app on the Play Store, you are able to get all that information, plus much more:

**Google Play Store:**

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

**iTunes:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293785/5442132

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem that i need to see the download & redownloads distributed by age , gender and other parameters which is related to my application.

Comment: BTW itunes connect doesn't show re downloads , he just shows new downloads

Comment: Ah! that is getting a little too specific, I am not sure how that would work with analytics.